# Parametrizing a pytest fixture that returns an array

Tags: pytest

I have to use an array of fixtures that I want to paramterize. I'll give the simplest example below.

## conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    client = do_some_stuff_to_setup_client()
    return client;
```

## test_file.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def data(client):
    ids = client.get_all_ids()
    return ids # returns array of numbers [1,2,3,4]

@pytest.mark.parametize('data', (array_of_ids_needed_here), indirect=True)
def test_something(client, data):
    client.do_stuff(data)
```

I want this to run against 1,2,3,4 but with indirect param it returns data = [1,2,3,4] not as 4 different numbers. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Somehow the code in your example doesn't make sense to me - `test_something` should parametrize the `data` fixture using the values that `data` itself returns?

Comment: Yes, so `data` needs to use `client` (another fixture in conftest) to return list of things to parameterize. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you want to parametrize the `test_something` with the values that `data` returns? Unfortunately, this is not possible with plain `pytest`, see [this issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349). You can try the [`pytest-lazy-fixture` plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/), but it's not safe for all use cases, AFAIK.

Comment: I tried this and doesn't seem to wrok in pytest-lazy-fixture though it should:
`@pytest.mark.parametize('data', [pytest.lazy_fixture('client').get_all_ids()])`

Comment: It should be `@pytest.mark.parametize('values', pytest.lazy_fixture('data'))`, and change `data` arg to `values` in `test_something` signature.